# Difference between MSC-A, MSC-B and FP-40

Tags: cisco

What's the difference between

- MSC-A
- MSC-B
- FP-40

on a CRS-1 8-S?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

[MSC-B](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps5763/ps5862/data_sheet_C78-457165.html) draws a little more power than [MSC-A](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps5763/ps5862/product_data_sheet09186a008022d5ee.html), but they are similar in functionality.

The [FP40](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps5763/data_sheet_c78-553673.html) doesn't have as much buffering as the MSC cards, and it doesn't have the top-end PPS switching speed that the MSC cards do.

Answer (score 2):

MSC has less bootflash space compared to MSC-B, and MSC-B has more surface mounted components, and as earlier said, uses slightly less power. MSC is going end-of-support earlier than MSC-B, probably partly due to the constrained bootflash space.

FP-40 has one less forwarding "ASIC" compared to MSC/MSC-B.